# CountDownTimer onfinish method run after change activity

Tags: android

I use CountDownTimer in my code and when i run app i have one problem that is when i go to next level ( go to next activity ) the timer should be stop and dont run the onfinish method but when the first level timer down it run the onfinish method and go to activity GameOver .

I use Intent to move between my activity and my CountDownTimer is :

```
new CountDownTimer(timeoflevel, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            txtclock2.setText("Time: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
        }

        public void onFinish() {

            txtclock2.setText("..Finish..");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Play.this , GameOver.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }.start();
```

Sorry for my easy question and thanks for reading .

Comment: the timer should be stop and don't run the onfinish, means you want to stop time inside onFinish() method

Comment: at first time your timer is working and when you go to next level it stop its not working i am right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;


countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeoflevel, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            txtclock2.setText("Time: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            txtclock2.setText("..Finish..");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Play.this , GameOver.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
}.start();
```

// and in OnStop

```
public void onStop(){
       countDownTimer.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call countDownTimer.cancel() before starting next level. It will cancel the counDownTimer and will not call onFinish.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onStop(){

   //Cancel your timer here before going to  next activity.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

//in on Resume()

countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeoflevel, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    txtclock2.setText("Time: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        //TODO perform operation
    }
    public void onFinish() {
        txtclock2.setText("..Finish..");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Play.this , GameOver.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}.start();

// Cancel Timer in onPause()

public void in onPause(){
    countDownTimer.cancel();
}
```